# projection document querying fields containing certain letters

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to get `MenuItems.find(..` to return those documents whose field "group" has a letter which is contained in "menuGroup"
Example:

If menuGroup is "a" then return the documents with their group equals to a.
if menuGroup is "ab" then return all documents with group field equals to "a" as well as documents with group field equals to "b".
Reading the [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection), I can't figure it out. Could you please help? Thanks

```
var items =
  [
    {menuItem: "task1", group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task2", group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task3", group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "task4", group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task5", group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task6", group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task7", group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "task8", group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "task9", group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "login", group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "logout", group: "a"}
  ]
if (!MenuItems.find().count()) {
    _.each(items, function (doc) {
        MenuItems.insert(doc);
    })
}

Meteor.publish('menuItems', function () {
    var menuGroup;
    if (!this.userId) { //no one is logged in
        menuGroup = 'a';
    } else {
        menuGroup = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).profile.menuGroup;
    }
    return MenuItems.find({group: menuGroup});  //what if menuGroup is "ab"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `menuGroup` and then use mongo's [$in](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator like this:

```js
return MenuItems.find({group: {$in: menuGroup.split('')}});
```

So if `menuGroup` was `'ab'` the selector would end up being `{group: {$in: ['a', 'b']}}`.